# Не работает apt-get upgrade: конфликт 32 и 64-х битных версий пакета

Tags: linux, ubuntu, debian, apt-get

```
$ sudo apt-get upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages will be upgraded:
...
99 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/266 MB of archives.
After this operation, 1,146 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Reading changelogs... Done
Extracting templates from packages: 100%
Preconfiguring packages ...
dpkg: error processing package libdb5.3:i386 (--configure):
 package libdb5.3:i386 5.3.28-9+deb8u1 cannot be configured because libdb5.3:amd64 is at a different version (5.3.28-9)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 libdb5.3:i386
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Как удалить лишнюю 64-битную версию и исправить эту ошибку?

Дополнительная информация:

```
$ dpkg --print-architecture 
i386

$ dpkg --print-foreign-architectures
```

Попытка удаления всех amd64 пакетов через aptitude тоже упирается в эту ошибку:

```
$ sudo aptitude purge ~i~ramd64
The following partially installed packages will be configured:
  libdb5.3 
No packages will be installed, upgraded, or removed.
0 packages upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 99 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B of archives. After unpacking 0 B will be used.
dpkg: error processing package libdb5.3:i386 (--configure):
 package libdb5.3:i386 5.3.28-9+deb8u1 cannot be configured because libdb5.3:amd64 is at a different version (5.3.28-9)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 libdb5.3:i386
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
Failed to perform requested operation on package.  Trying to recover:
dpkg: error processing package libdb5.3:i386 (--configure):
 package libdb5.3:i386 5.3.28-9+deb8u1 cannot be configured because libdb5.3:amd64 is at a different version (5.3.28-9)
dpkg: error processing package libdb5.3:amd64 (--configure):
 package libdb5.3:amd64 5.3.28-9 cannot be configured because libdb5.3:i386 is at a different version (5.3.28-9+deb8u1)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 libdb5.3:i386
 libdb5.3:amd64
```

Comment: а истории, о том, как он оказался в системе нет? стоит попробовать удалить через `dpkg` с какими-нить строгими опциями... например с `--no-triggers`.

Comment: История здесь несущественный фактор, впрочем вопрос уже неактуален.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Добавляем 64-ю архитектуру в dpkg:

```
$ sudo dpkg --add-architecture amd64
```

Выполняем попытку удаления установленных 64-х пакетов с помощью aptitude:

```
$ sudo aptitude purge ~i~ramd64
The following partially installed packages will be configured:
  libdb5.3 
No packages will be installed, upgraded, or removed.
0 packages upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 99 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B of archives. After unpacking 0 B will be used.
dpkg: error processing package libdb5.3:i386 (--configure):
 package libdb5.3:i386 5.3.28-9+deb8u1 cannot be configured because libdb5.3:amd64 is at a different version (5.3.28-9)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 libdb5.3:i386
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
Failed to perform requested operation on package.  Trying to recover:
dpkg: error processing package libdb5.3:i386 (--configure):
 package libdb5.3:i386 5.3.28-9+deb8u1 cannot be configured because libdb5.3:amd64 is at a different version (5.3.28-9)
dpkg: error processing package libdb5.3:amd64 (--configure):
 package libdb5.3:amd64 5.3.28-9 cannot be configured because libdb5.3:i386 is at a different version (5.3.28-9+deb8u1)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 libdb5.3:i386
 libdb5.3:amd64

Current status: 114 broken [+114], 141 new [+124].
There are 124 newly obsolete packages.
```

И затем успешно выполняем эту же команду ещё раз:

```
$ sudo aptitude purge ~i~ramd64
The following packages will be REMOVED:  
  apt-transport-https:amd64{p} gcc-4.9-base:amd64{p} ...
```

Теперь убираем 64-ю архитектуру из dpkg:

```
dpkg --remove-architecture amd64
```

И наконец выполняем обновление:

```
$ sudo apt-get upgrade
```